# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inserts new row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert new row to my MySQL table unless row with same value in `campign_id` column exists, which in this case i would like to update the row.
My query is :

```
INSERT INTO prv_campaigns SET 
website_id = %s,account_id = %s,campaign_id = %s,campaign_name = %s,start_date = %s,
end_date = %s,targeting_type = %s,enabled = %s,status = %s,bid_type = %s,
default_bid = %s,min_bid = %s,max_bid = %s,budget = %s,cost = %s,ctr = %s,
utm_codes = %s,country_codes = %s,country_targeting = %s,opt = %s,
device_targeting = %s,language_targeting = %s,exclude_low_volume = %s
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
campaign_name = %s,
start_date = %s,
end_date = %s,
targeting_type = %s,
enabled = %s,
status = %s,
bid_type = %s,
default_bid = %s,
min_bid = %s,
max_bid = %s,
budget = %s,
cost = %s,
ctr = %s,
utm_codes = %s,
country_codes = %s,
country_targeting = %s,
opt = %s,
device_targeting = %s,
language_targeting = %s,
exclude_low_volume
```

and table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `prv_campaigns` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modification_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `website_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `targeting_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_bid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_bid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_bid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `budget` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ctr` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utm_codes` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_codes` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_targeting` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_targeting` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_targeting` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclude_low_volume` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ndx` (`website_id`,`account_id`,`campaign_id`,`campaign_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14334 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

now i was clearly wrong thinking that since `campaign_id` is a UNIQUE KEY then the update part of the query will take place, but instead a new row created in my database...any idea how to fix this? thx

Answer (score 1):

`campaign_id` is *not* a unique key.  It is one element of a four-part unique key.  The four *in combination* are unique.  Not each one individually.

If you want it to be unique, then declare it as such:  `unique (campaign_id)`.  You may also want the other fields to be "individually" unique.

You can add this constraint to the table, if you like:

```
alter table prv_campaigns  add constraint unq_campaigns_campaign_id
    unique (campaign_id);
```

Comment: Assuming i can't alter the table, is there a solution i can implement in the presented query ?

Comment: @yarivbar . . . Not really.  If `campaign_id` should be unique, it should be declared as such.